# E4 Application - importing plugins without Bundle-SymbolicName

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, manifest, e4

I am working on an project which is a POM and manifest driven E4 application containing a plugin platform project which builds a local p2 as my target for the larger RCP app. A necessary dependency is older and has within its jar a manifest which contains no Bundle-SymbolicName. As such, I am unable to import the plugin to my local p2 repo and subsequent target definition, since the feature.xml of my platform project cannot resolve the plugin.

Is there any way in which to import this plugin to my local p2 without a Bundle-SymbolicName attributed to it?

Thanks

feature.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
  id="example.p2.feature"
  label="Example Maven Dependencies"
  version="1.0.0.qualifier"
  provider-name="">

    <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      Base feature for example project to be built on
    </description>

    <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
    </copyright>

    <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
    </license>

    <plugin
         id="org.apache.commons.collections"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

    <plugin
         id="org.apache.thrift"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

    <plugin
         id="org.apache.commons.pool"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: ecagent
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_22
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.1.1
```

Comment: It sounds like you may have an old 2.0 style Eclipse plugin which is not going to work at all without some extra plugins. What does the plugin.xml look like?

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for the quick response. I'm not sure which plugin.xml you are referencing. I have updated the question with a subset from my feature.xml inside of the platform project.

Comment: Well what is it that doesn't have an Bundle-SymbolicName? What is it that the feature.xml cannot resolve?

Comment: @greg-449 the manifest.mf file of the old plugin has been added to the question. For a newer plugin, this file would be populated with the Bundle-SymbolicName field which would then be added to the feature.xml file as a plugin, inserting the field as the id. Since this field is missing, eclipse and the feature.xml cannot resolve this jar as a plugin when it pulls the dependency using its POM

Comment: As I already asked what does the plugin.xml of this plugin look like?

Comment: @greg-449 thank you for your patience with this. There is no plugin.xml for the plugin which has a missing Bundle-SymbolicName. It is not an OSGi plugin; just a simple java jar

Comment: Then it is not a plugin and you can't treat as one. Plain jars must be included in a plugin - you will have to write a simple plugin to use it or include it in one of your existing plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jar which does not contain a `Bundle-SymbolicName` entry (and does not contain a `plugin.xml` in the old Eclipse 2.0 style) is not a plug-in and you can't reference it as though it was one.

You can either include the jar as part of one of your existing plug-ins (make sure it is listed in the `build.properties if you do this) or you can create a new plug-in just the contain the jar.